# Caida rendimiento videojuego delphi

Tags: delphi, rendimiento

Vuelvo de nuevo para consultar ya que no logro entender el problema.
Ya realize pruebas con vcl normal, con canvas, con canvas d2d, y hasta en fmx que tiene aceleracion por hardware.

Mi problema es el mismo. **Cuando hay muchos objetos en pantalla, en un formulario, el rendimiento disminuye.**

Decidi probar en FMX con un formulario 3d, y me puse a monitorear con el MSI after burner los fps y la utilización de recursos. Y pasado los 50 objetos creados, la aplicacion disminuye sus fps pero NO UTILIZA PARA NADA LOS RECURSOS DE HARDWARE.

mi pequeño codigo para realizar pruebas :
En este ejemplo, creo objetos imagenes3d en tiempo de ejecucion y los muevo en pantalla, maximo 100 objetos.
(He probado realizando dibujos en canvas,creando un solo frame pero la situacion es la misma)

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var g : integer;
begin
randomize;
g := random (20) ;
 if g = 10 then begin
    for var i := 1 to 100 do begin
      if not assigned(vector[i]) then begin
        vector[i] := timage3d.Create(vector[i]);
        vector[i].Bitmap := image3d1.Bitmap;
        vector[i].Parent := image3d1.Parent;
        vector[i].Width := 100;
        vector[i].Height:= 100;
        vector[i].Position.x:= 100;
        vector[i].Position.y:= 100;
        vector[i].Position.z:= 0;
        vector[i].Projection := image3d1.Projection;
        break  ;
      end
    end  ;
 end;

   for var t := 1 to 100 do begin
      if assigned(vector[t]) then begin
        vector[t].Position.x :=  vector[t].Position.x + 2;
        vector[t].Position.y :=  vector[t].Position.y + 2;
        //vector[t].RotationAngle.x :=   vector[t].RotationAngle.x + 1;
      end

   end
end;
```

Esto es todo el codigo de ejemplo, y todo el codigo dentro del timer, no hay nada mas. Lo realize como prueba. Para dar a entenderme.
Les muestro una imagen de la aplicacion de prueba, donde se crean imagenes en tiempo de ejecucion y se mueven por pantalla.
Cual es el motivo de la relantizacion ?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pregunta interesante, pero faltan un par de cosas en el código para poder probar. Por lo menos, las propiedades del objeto image3d1, incluyendo el bitmap y projection. Si actualizas la pregunta, dejame un comentario y con gusto le doy una mirada.

Comment: Hola, gracias de nuevo.

Comment: No conozco a fondo las propiedades projection. Esta propiedad la incluye el objeto IMAGE3D1, que es un objeto timage3d. Al poner el valor en (screen), me visualiza el formulario como si fuese 2D. El cuanto al bitmap, fue cargado manualmente desde el object inspector, es un png comun de 130px. Esta prueba la realize en Firemonkey con un formulario 3d , pensando que este tipo de formularios me dejarian trabajar con muchas imagenes con soltura. Pero esto me pasa igual, dibujando en canvas de la vcl. Asi que pienso que hay conceptos que no tengo claros.

Comment: Repetí algo similar a lo que haces, solo que utilizando ```TFloatAnimation``` para mover las imágenes y efectivamente el rendimiento cae cuando hay más de 50 objetos en pantalla, lo cual me parece lógico por la manera de hacerlo. Hice otra prueba básica, manteniendo las posiciones de las imágnes en una lista y dibujando las imágenes en un bitmap que luego asigno a un TImageViewer, y con 100 imágenes, logro mantener 60/64 fps sin problema haciendo todo en el hilo principal. Para más objetos, se puede trasladar parte del proceso a un hilo secundario.

Comment: Sin embargo, el código tiene poco que ver con lo que planteas en la pregunta y creo que rebasa lo que sería aceptable en una respuesta de StackOverflow (en cuanto a extensión de la misma). https://imgur.com/IMipP1U

Comment: Realize pruebas en un formulario comun, utilizando puros TIMAGE, y puedo aumentar significativamente la cantidad de objetos. Pero no comprendo cual es el error o el porque, cuando me dices que es logico. Ya que no me sucede con otros componentes. Sobretodo me llama la atencion LA NO UTILIZACION de recursos. Porque la aplicacion casi no hace uso del CPU, ni gpu, o por lo menos es lo que me muestra el afterburner. De todas maneras te agradezco tu tiempo y conocimiento

Comment: Cuándo digo que me parece lógico por la manera de hacerlo, me refiero a que cada cambio de posición de un control (como es el TImage) va a invalidar el formulario y, finalmente, a lanzar el re-pintado de este. Esto es sub-optimo, cuando menos. Dado que el re-pintado se hace mediante una cola de mensajes varias invalidaciones pueden colapsar en un solo re-pintado, pero no creo que sea la manera en la que funcionan los juegos (reconociendo que no he programado sino los más sencillos).

Comment: Por ello el enfoque de mi segunda prueba es diferente. La escena completa se dibuja _de un solo_, con lo cual se logra hacer de manera más eficiente, incluso en el hilo principal.

Comment: La poca utilización de recursos se deriva de lo mismo. Las operaciones de re-pintado tienden a ser lentas. Sé que puede ser algo contra-intuitivo, pero para sacar provecho de la CPU/GPU, usualmente lo que se hace es hacer muchas operaciones _fuera de pantalla_ y todas estas se llevan allí en un solo paso.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno estuve realizando casi las mismas pruebas , en un formulario comun utilizando Firemonkey. Si bien realize la misma prueba, no estoy notando relantizaciones.
Pero todavia no probe sobrecargando el formulario con objetos haciendolos rebotar y que se queden en la pantalla. Entiendo que lo ideal seria utilizar el canvas, pero como estoy realizando pruebas, primero me puse a experimentar con cosas basicas. Solo me queda hacer rebotar las imagenes para que el formulario se cargue y ver cuanto es lo que aguanta.

Como mi intencion es trabajar 2D, cambie el FORM3D. Pero aun me llama la atencion, que trabajando con 3d se me relantize la aplicacion, suponiendo que esta deberia tener mas potencia.

Calculo que los formularios delphi, no son ideales para trabajar videojuegos. Aunque yo solo estoy experimentando con cosas sencillas. O se debe trabajar de otra manera para dotar de potencia grafica a las aplicaciones.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var g : integer;
begin
randomize;
g := random (20) ;
 if g = 10 then begin
    for var i := 1 to 1000 do begin
      if not assigned(vector[i]) then begin
        vector[i] := timage.Create(vector[i]);
        vector[i].Bitmap := imagecontrol1.Bitmap;
        vector[i].Parent := imagecontrol1.Parent;
        vector[i].Width := 100;
        vector[i].Height:= 100;
        vector[i].Position.x:= 100;
        vector[i].Position.y:= 100;
        break  ;
      end;
    end  ;
 end;

   for var t := 1 to 1000 do begin
      if assigned(vector[t]) then begin
        vector[t].Position.x :=  vector[t].Position.x + 2;
        vector[t].Position.y :=  vector[t].Position.y + 2;
        //vector[t].RotationAngle.x :=   vector[t].RotationAngle.x + 1;
      end
   end
end;
```